# Saving sequentially named images from URL Directory in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, sequential

Is there perhaps a way to make a PHP script that downloads images that are sequentially named? For example:

`https://example.com/picture/1.jpg` to `https://example.com/picture/100.jpg` meaning downloading images named 1.jpg that count up to 100.jpg in sequential order and save it onto my computer?

Comment: Yes, there is. search for `curl`. zlib (or something similar) might be helpful, too.

Comment: @Ventality What is the status of this question?  If you have found a solution please post your findings as an answer so future readers can benefit from your research.  If another question on SO has a suitable answer, please delete your question.